# Post text and files in Java/Android in UTF-8

Tags: java, php, android, http

I have the following code for posting a text and a file with http:

```
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        entity.addPart("field_1", new StringBody(textField));
        entity.addPart("field_2", new FileBody(new File(filepath)));
        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
```

It works nice the problem is that I need the textField value to be encoded in UTF-8.Any ideas?

Editted: Found an error in the code, posting the working answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sollution is to use:

```
new StringBody(textField,"text/plain",Charset.forName("UTF-8")
```